# Take elements of a matrix row wise and puts them in a column vector

Tags: r, matrix, data-manipulation

This may be basic but I want to take elements of a matrix row wise and puts them in a column vector. How to do that?

```
#A matrix
BETA <- matrix(c(0.215, 0.031, 0.003, 0.323), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2)
#I want to achieve this:
0.215 
0.031
0.003 
0.323
```

Comment: matrix(t(BETA))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to get a `numeric` class. Here is how to do it.

```r
BETA <-matrix(c(0.215, 0.031, 0.003, 0.323), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2)
BETA_column = as.numeric( t(BETA) )
BETA_column
#> [1] 0.215 0.031 0.003 0.323
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>